# What kind of number 9.00000000e-01 is?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I've declared a `x` variable and filled it with the `np.arange(-1, 1, 0.1)`. The `print(x)` method gives me something like that:

```
[ -1.00000000e+00  -9.00000000e-01  -8.00000000e-01  -7.00000000e-01
  -6.00000000e-01  -5.00000000e-01  -4.00000000e-01  -3.00000000e-01
  -2.00000000e-01  -1.00000000e-01  -2.22044605e-16   1.00000000e-01
   2.00000000e-01   3.00000000e-01   4.00000000e-01   5.00000000e-01
   6.00000000e-01   7.00000000e-01   8.00000000e-01   9.00000000e-01]
```

What kind of numbers are those? How can I convert them to, e.g `float` type? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can easily find out what they are with `x.dtype`. See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: `x.dtype` returns `dtype('float64')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(-1,1,0.1)
>>> print(x)
[ -1.00000000e+00  -9.00000000e-01  -8.00000000e-01  -7.00000000e-01
-6.00000000e-01  -5.00000000e-01  -4.00000000e-01  -3.00000000e-01
-2.00000000e-01  -1.00000000e-01  -2.22044605e-16   1.00000000e-01
 2.00000000e-01   3.00000000e-01   4.00000000e-01   5.00000000e-01
 6.00000000e-01   7.00000000e-01   8.00000000e-01   9.00000000e-01]
>>> type(x[0])
<type 'numpy.float64'>

>>> print(x.tolist())
[-1.0, -0.9, -0.8, -0.7000000000000001, -0.6000000000000001, -0.5000000000000001,         -0.40000000000000013, -0.30000000000000016, -0.20000000000000018, -0.1000000000000002, -2.220446049250313e-16, 0.09999999999999964, 0.19999999999999973, 0.2999999999999998, 0.3999999999999997, 0.49999999999999956, 0.5999999999999996, 0.6999999999999997, 0.7999999999999996, 0.8999999999999995]
>>> type(x.tolist()[0])
<type 'float'>
```

The type is initially a numpy float64.

Comment: Note that you can use `x.dtype` to get the type more directly.

Answer (score 10):

The number `9.00000000e-01` already **is** a floating point number.

It's written in [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation) and is equivalent to `9 * 10**-1` or `0.9`.

Answer (score 1):

Those are floating point values written using [scientific notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation). So, `9e-1` is *9×10<sup>-1</sup>* or *0.9*.